# Java Null Pointer Exception: Tokenizing Input for Lexer

Tags: java, tokenize

I'm getting the following error when I run my .jar file in the CMD prompt:

```
C:\Users\Mikael\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\cs413CompilerProject\dist>
java -jar "cs413CompilerProject.jar" "C:\Users\Mikael\Documents\NetBeansProjects\cs413
CompilerProject\cs413Compiler\simple.x"
User's current working directory: 
C:\Users\Mikael\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\cs413CompilerProject\dist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: lexer\setup\tokens 
(The system cannot find the path specified)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at lexer.setup.TokenSetup.initTokenClasses(TokenSetup.java:77)
        at lexer.setup.TokenSetup.main(TokenSetup.java:35)
```

and the code that it's referring to is (starting on line 24 of TokenSetup.java and ending at line 35):

```
24  public class TokenSetup {
25  private String type, value; // token type/value for new token
26  private int tokenCount = 0;
27  private BufferedReader in;
28  private PrintWriter table, symbols; // files used for new classes
29  
30  /**
31   *
32   * @param args
33   */
34  public static void main(String args[]) {
35      new TokenSetup().initTokenClasses();}
```

then the other reference under TokenSetup.initTokenClasses:

```
77  public void initTokenClasses() {
78      table.println("/*********************");
79      table.println("*");
80      table.println("* @Author Mikael M");
81  //... print a bunch of things
}
```

Full code:

```
package lexer.setup;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
//
///**
// *  TokenSetup class is used to read the tokens from file <i>tokens</i>
// *  and automatically build the 2 classes/files <i>TokenType.java</i> 
// *  and <i>Sym.java</i><br>
// *  Therefore, if there is any change to the tokens then we only need to
// *  modify the file <i>tokens</i> and run this program again before using the
// *  compiler
//*/
public class TokenSetup {
    private String type, value; // token type/value for new token
    private int tokenCount = 0;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter table, symbols; // files used for new classes

    /**
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TokenSetup().initTokenClasses();
    }

    TokenSetup() {
        try {
            System.out.println("User's current working directory: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));          
            String sep = System.getProperty("file.separator");
            in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("lexer" + sep + "setup" + sep + "tokens"));
            table = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("lexer" + sep + "TokenType.java"));
            symbols = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("lexer" + sep + "Tokens.java"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

///**
// *  read next line which contains token information;<br>
// *  each line will contain the token type used in lexical analysis and
// *  the printstring of the token: e.g.<br><ul>
// *  <li>Program program</li>
// *  <li>Int int</li>
// *  <li>BOOLean boolean</li></ul>
// * @throws IOException 
// */
    public void getNextToken() throws IOException {
        try {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());
            type = st.nextToken();
            value = st.nextToken();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("***tokens file does not have 2 strings per line***");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
            throw new IOException("***End of File***");
        }
        tokenCount++;
    }

///**
// *  initTokenClasses will create the 2 files
//*/
    public void initTokenClasses() {
        table.println("/*********************");
        table.println("*");
        table.println("* @Author Mikael C. Miller");
        table.println("*");
        table.println("* SFSU 9/20/15");
        table.println("*");
        table.println("* CSc 413");
        table.println("*");
        table.println("*/");
        table.println("package lexer;");
        table.println(" ");
        table.println("/**");
        table.println(" *  This file is automatically generated<br>");
        table.println(" *  it contains the table of mappings from token");
        table.println(" *  constants to their Symbols");
        table.println("*/");
        table.println("public class TokenType {");
        table.println("   public static java.util.HashMap<Tokens,Symbol> tokens = new java.util.HashMap<Tokens,Symbol>();");
        table.println("   public TokenType() {");
        symbols.println("package lexer;");
        symbols.println(" ");
        symbols.println("/**");
        symbols.println(" *  This file is automatically generated<br>");
        symbols.println(" *  - it contains the enumberation of all of the tokens");
        symbols.println("*/");
        symbols.println("public enum Tokens {");
        symbols.print("  BogusToken");

        while (true) {
            try {
                getNextToken();
            } catch (IOException e) {break;}

            String symType = "Tokens." + type;

            table.println("     tokens.put(" + symType +
                ", Symbol.symbol(\"" + value + "\"," + symType + "));");

            if (tokenCount % 5 == 0) {
                symbols.print(",\n    "+ type);
            } else {
                symbols.print("," + type);
            }
        }

        table.println("   }");
        table.println("}");
        table.close();
        symbols.println("\n}");
        symbols.close();
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the constructor of `TokenSetup`, a `FileNotFound` exception is thrown, but you do nothing with it other than to just print the message of the exception to `System.out`.  Then, your constructor returns as if everything went fine, and your `main()` function proceeds to call `initTokenClasses()` on the partially initialized instance of `TokenSetup`.  I don't even want to think what is going to happen as a result of that.  I am not even going to look into it.  It is irrelevant.  The problem is with the first exception which is thrown, the `FileNotFound` exception.  The `NullPointerException` which happens afterwards is a [red herring (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

When you have an exception, you cannot just proceed as if nothing happened.  Exceptions cannot be swept under the rug.  Do this instead:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
```

and

```
    TokenSetup() throws Exception
```

and stop trying to catch exceptions if you do not know what to do with them.

This way, when an exception is thrown, your program stops immediately, instead of proceeding further down and confusing you with more exceptions that are inevitably thrown.

Comment: Thank you for that tip. I'll add it into my code. I've never really been able to understand exceptions, so this helps a bit!

Comment: It is okay, exceptions are one of those initially hard notions to *really* understand, so it is to be expected that you, still a student, do not have a firm grip on them yet.  However, exceptions are crucial for writing software nowadays, and employers almost always ask about them in job interviews.  To make matters worse, university professors are not *necessarily* up to date with exceptions, so do not rely on the university to teach you how to use exceptions properly; find some articles from people in the industry.

Comment: One person I can think of is Erik Lippert : http://ericlippert.com/category/exception-handling/